# Run cherrypy in Google App engine

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I am trying to run a web application using CherryPY framework in Google App engine . I am unable to run the basic helloworld code in development server locally (from downloaded the SDK )

I am getting `ImportError: No module named cherrypy`. Although I did install 
cherrypy using pip install and the same code works using

`python hello.py` ( removing the google import )

this is my **hello.py**

```
import random
import string
import cherrypy
from google.appengine.ext.webapp.util import run_wsgi_app

class StringGenerator(object):
    @cherrypy.expose
    def index(self):
        return "Hello world!"

    @cherrypy.expose
    def generate(self):
        return ''.join(random.sample(string.hexdigits, 8))


if __name__ == '__main__':
   cherrypy.quickstart(StringGenerator(), '/')
```

and my **app.yaml** file

```
version: 1
runtime: python27
api_version: 1
threadsafe: true
# [START handlers]
handlers:
- url: /.*
  script: hello.app
# [END handlers]

# [START libraries]
libraries:
- name: webapp2
  version: latest
- name: jinja2
  version: latest
# [END libraries]
```

Answer (score 3):

Cherrypy is not bundled as part of App Engine but since it's a pure python framework, you can resort to vendoring to add it to your project so the development server can pick it up:

```
$ mkdir lib

$ pip install -t lib cherrypy
```

Create a new `appengine_config.py` file in your application's root, same location as your `app.yaml` etc... with the following contents:

```
from google.appengine.ext import vendor

vendor.add('lib')
```

More info can be found [here](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/libraries27) and [here](https://www.jeffgodwyll.com/posts/2015/google-appegine-vendoring-done-right/).

Answer (score 1):

If you're using Python 3+ and CherryPy, you can follow [this](http://hacagusae.appspot.com/post/-2/?lang=es) tutorial in order to deploy your web app / API REST on Google App Engine. I hope this can help you.